# How does Apache Spark implement the shuffle phase?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I was wondering how does Apache Spark implements the shuffle phase. Does it use the same technique as in MapReduce ? For example :

```
rddB = rddA.map1.groupByKey();
rddX = rddB.map2.map3.saveAsTextFile();
rddY = rddB.map4.map5.saveAsTextFile();
```

Does it perform map1 then partitions by key and saves the intermediate data on disk (memory)?

Then reads the intermediate files 2 times, once for the map2 map3 branch and a second time for map4 map5 without calculating rddB again even though we did not do an implicit cache on rddB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Spark behaves in a slightly different way. First of all, Spark doesn't perform actually the operation when the line you have written is encountered, but it creates a DAG of the operations to be performed to obtain a given RDD or result. In fact, Spark's operations are split in two main categories: transformations and actions; it executes them only when an action is encountered.

Moreover, Spark stores intermediate results only when you tell it to do so, i.e. when you invoke `persist` or `cache` on a RDD. If you don't do that, it will perform all the operation to obtain a given result up to the root of the DAG (i.e. reading them from the files).

The previous statement is not really true. In fact, the manual says [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

> Spark also automatically persists some intermediate data in shuffle
>   operations (e.g. reduceByKey), even without users calling persist.
>   This is done to avoid recomputing the entire input if a node fails
>   during the shuffle. We still recommend users call persist on the
>   resulting RDD if they plan to reuse it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of how Spark works and the difference between transformations and actions, but I'm seeing a strange behavior with groupByKey. Spark is using the result of groupByKey as if it does an implicit cache on rddB to calculate rddX and rddY without calculating rddB twice (could it be that the intermediate shuffle files are being read again without calculation of rddB ?).

Comment: How do you state that it is doing an implicit cache?

Comment: It looks like an implict cache, because when Spark calculates the rddY it doesn't go all the way back to calcualte rddB but uses its result directly.

Comment: But how can you say that? Why do you say it does not recompute rddB?

Comment: It takes less time to calculate rddY than rddX, and I can see a missing stage that it says is already calculated.

Comment: You're right, in the link I posted says: "Spark also automatically persists some intermediate data in shuffle operations (e.g. reduceByKey), even without users calling persist. This is done to avoid recomputing the entire input if a node fails during the shuffle. We still recommend users call persist on the resulting RDD if they plan to reuse it.". So, the result of your groupByKey is actually cached automatically.